# Decomposing SVD of this dataset by hand (perspective)

Tags: pca, svd

I have the following data matrix

$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-3 & -3 & -3 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$

where the rows are data points and columns dimensions

I am asked to optimize by hand the SVD parameters.

---

Apparently the answer is this but I have no idea the intuition to get here by hand

$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0\\
-3a & 0\\
2a & 0\\
0 & b\\
0 & -2b\\
0 & b
\end{array}\right]*\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha_{1} & 0\\
0 & \alpha_{2}
\end{array}\right]*\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
c & c & c & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & d & d
\end{array}\right]$

How do I solve this problem? I can see the first 3 dimensions are collinear, and the last 2 dimensions collinear amongst the points

I am also told to solve for all those values.

Comment: Hint: the original matrix has a clear block form.  Each of the nonzero blocks is, just as clearly, the outer product of two vectors.